# How to get variable from other sql table in laravel?

Tags: php, sql, laravel

i have 2 table 1st.   users 2nd  rebeatlogs.

for users table

```
$amount = $request->amount;

$user = Auth::user()->amount;
```

in rebeatlogs (based on user_id) table  i have "balance" column  instead of "amount" column  and is not using "auth"
how i will build simillar variable  for  $amount  and $user  in case of rebeatlogs column which is not using auth.

complete code for explaination :

```
public function checkAmount(Request $request)
    {
        $amount = $request->amount;
        $met = $request->method_id;
        $method = ManualPayment::findOrFail($met);
        $charge = $method->method_fix + (($amount * $method->method_percent) /100);
        $hit = $charge + $amount;
        $user = Auth::user()->amount;
```

Comment: Questions is unclear. I can't figure out what you are asking.

Comment: now you can understand?

Answer (score 1):

```
    $userId = Auth::user()->id;  
    $user = Rebeatlog::where('user_id', '=', $userId)
      ->first()
      ->balance;
```

Comment: please check question again i have  added some more details

Comment: in rebeatlogs (based on user_id) table i have "balance" column instead of "amount" column and is not using "auth" -->> did I correct understand this ?

Comment: yes . mean rebeatlogs table  and  2 colmns 1st . user_id and 2nd is balance

Comment: So here you go ! ) That's actually what you need. You know user_id - just retrieve rebeatlog by this column and get the balance.

Comment: but whatwould be variable for  "$user"     as for  amount of user   $user = Auth::user()->amount; incase of "balance  " in case of rebeatlog

Comment: in your case var $rebeatlogAmount will be used as $user. Your code looks very strange, sorry )) But I fixed my script to make it clear for you what I ment,

Comment: Thanks. But now what will be for $amount

Comment: the same: $amount = $request->amount;

Comment: But request is as $request which is var for users table

Comment: $request is the instance of Request class - that's not related to User

Comment: Please can you share a link about instance of  request